# How to change size of image and put it into a rectangle box

Tags: javascript

First time associating with javascript and have been trying to adjust size of thumbnail(image from database) but cant seem to get it and also i tried using canvas to acchieve a rectangle box but it does not show at all too. Thank you.

Here are my JS codes:

```js
//This function is to call the movies api and get all the movies
//that is showing in Shaw Theatres for Showing Now and Coming Soon
function getRestaurantData() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', restaurant_url, true);

  //This function will be called when data returns from the web api
  request.onload = function() {
    //get all the movies records into our movie array
    restaurant_array = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    //fetch comments
    //fetchComments();
    //call the function so as to display all movies tiles for "Now Showing"
    displayRestaurant();
  };
  //This command starts the calling of the movies web api
  request.send();
}

//This function is to display the movies tiles (edit index pg the thumbnail)
//that filters based on "Now Showing" or "Coming Soon“
function displayRestaurant() {
  var table = document.getElementById("restaurantTable");
  var restaurantCount = 0;
  var message = "";

  table.innerHTML = "";
  totalRestaurant = restaurant_array.length;
  for (var count = 0; count < totalRestaurant; count++) {
    // if (restaurant_array[count].availability == category) 
    // {            
    var thumbnail = restaurant_array[count].thumb;
    var resname = restaurant_array[count].restaurant_name;
    var cell = '<div class="col-md-3" style="float: none; margin: 0 auto;">' +

      '<div class="front">' +
      '<a id="restaurants" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#resModal" item=' + count + '>' +

      '<img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src=' + thumbnail + ' />' +

      // '<canvas id="mybox" width="400" height = "400"></canvas>' +

      '</a>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="back">' +
      '<div class="bg-dark mystyle text-center py-3" >' +
      '<span>' + resname + '</span><br>' +
      '<button href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#resModal" item="' + count + '" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick="showRestaurantDetails(this)" >See More</button>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>';
    table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', cell);
    restaurantCount++;

  }
  message = restaurantCount + " Restaurants ";
  document.getElementById("summary").textContent = message;
  document.getElementById("parent").textContent = "";
}
```

Comment: Please click _edit_ then `[<>]` snippet editor and show us a [mcve] with relevant frameworks

Comment: im sorry i cant find the <> button

Comment: Click edit and the the Burton with <> on the button

Comment: What is the `count` ?. you have an error in the snippet.

Comment: alright i re edited it

Comment: Try `request.onload = function() {
    restaurant_array = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    displayRestaurant(restaurant_array);
  };` and have `function displayRestaurant(restaurant_array) {`

Comment: i need to change the size of the thumbnail loaded though?

Comment: like in my visual studios it loads the image of the thumbnail from the database fine even though it is not clickable

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your image source is valid jpeg or base64 you can add `object-fit` CSS property to img tag to adjust and fit the image in rectangle.

```
<img src="thumnail.jpeg" class="img-rectangle"/>
```

And CSS code as this,

```
.img-rectangle { object-fit: cover; }
```

You can refer to object-fit CSS property from this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp).

Comment: but my thumbnail is actually a variable from my sql database

Comment: var thumbnail = restaurant_array[count].thumb;

Comment: @chloeong can you find out what is the value of thumbnail variable? You can use console.log(thumbnail) to print the value in web browser console.

Comment: do i have to go to my webpage and click inspect and type in console.log(thumbnail) into the console?

Comment: @chloeong just add console.log(thumbnail) below your var thumbnail line

Comment: i think it is restaurant.js:35